# How to surface content of a custom Tab App for unified searching in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are building a custom tab application for Microsoft Teams. The data is stored in our database.

We have looked extensively at ways to get search to work, and short of creating a personal tab with our own search implementation, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this. We need our users to be able to use the standard search features in Teams to find the content they have created both in Teams' native tools and in our tab application.

One option we explored is implementing a Microsoft Search Connector to surface our content, but Teams seems to use its own search implementation instead of integrating with the rest of Microsoft's search ecosystem.

Comment: We are investigating this, and will update you soon with resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Developing custom search implementation for MS Teams isn't supported as of now. To add this feature for future considerations you can raise a user voice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)